# Steps for compiling Pro*C code

Tags: oracle-pro-c

Please let me know how to compile Pro*C code. How are the queries converted to a C file?

Answer (score 4):

Better off looking at the Oracle documentation, say [here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14407/toc.htm), but basically you precompile the Pro*C into regular C. The precompiler converts your SQL calls into library statements. Then you link and it all works magically.

The docs use this image to help describe it:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

I assume you have unix or linux.

Have a .pc file ready for precompilation with the pro*c compiler, use the command below to get the cpp file.

```
 proc CODE=cpp CPP_SUFFIX=cpp PARSE=NONE sample.pc
```

After getting "sample.cpp" file  compile on unix/linux with the following command to get the executable.

```
g++ *.cpp -I $ORACLE_HOME/precomp/ -L $ORACLE_HOME/lib -lclntsh -o a.out
```

That should do it. For windows I haven't had any luck compiling with pro*c. Here is the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46047295/how-to-compile-oracle-proc-files-pc-with-g-in-windows-10?rq=1) I have asked on SO.