# How to compile oracle Pro*c files (.pc ) with g++ in windows 10

Tags: windows, oracle, powershell, g++, oracle-pro-c

I have two machines one with unix (with oracle,pro*c and g++)and one with windows 10 (with oracle,pro*c and g++[mingw-64])

I have a .pc file that I precomplie with the pro*c compiler with following command on windows powershell as well as on unix.

```
 proc CODE=cpp CPP_SUFFIX=cpp PARSE=NONE sample.pc
```

After getting "sample.cpp" file I can easily compile and run the executable on unix with the following command

```
g++ *.cpp -I $ORACLE_HOME/precomp/ -L $ORACLE_HOME/lib -lclntsh -o a.out
```

Now I want to do the same thing (compilation of the generated .cpp file using g++ and linking it with a oracle pro*c lib file [lclntsh in case of unix]) on windows but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: What is a target of executable file? ELF?

Comment: @0xdb target would be a windows executable file (.exe)

Comment: Do you tried to execute last comand line with `-o sample.exe`?

Comment: @0xdb yeah I have tried but it gives an error "ld.exe lclntsh not found" ... I think it's because the linker file is different for Unix and Windows

Comment: I also have tried following the link https://www.developpez.net/forums/d625692/bases-donnees/oracle/interfaces-programmation/pro-c-compiler-sous-windows/ but without success

Comment: libclntsh.a is not available on windows. You could either create liboci.a from oci.dll with dlltools and than try to link it, or compile windows executable with mingw-w64 cross copiler under unix.